# Filter through service from inside angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I want to use a directive to display a set of data. for that I have made an element like so : `<jobs type="1" />`; the attribute type determine the type of job user should see, and to filter in my template I have the following code : `<div ng-repeat="job in jobs | filter:{'type':type}">{{job.title}}</div>`.

**The problem** I am having is that I cant figure out how to take the attribute value from my element and push it through along with my service result without making angular angry.

My Directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('jobs', jobsDirective);

jobsDirective.$inject = ['jobService','$scope','$sce'];


    function jobsDirective(jobService, $scope, $sce) {

        //this return results
        var jobs = jobService.getAllJobs().success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            return data;
        });


        return {
            restrict:'E',
            replace:true,
            templateUrl:'templates/jobs.html',
            scope: {    
                type:'@'
            },
            link: function(scope){
                scope.jobs = jobs;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to create a controller function for your directive, then inject the scope service in the controller and you will can access to 'type' attribute. Based in this value call your service inside controller function

Comment: can I create controller for directive ? cant find a reference for it in google

Comment: scope.jobs is a promise of HTTP response. You need an array of jobs. When asking a question that makes "angular angry", post the complete error message instead of letting us guess.

Comment: thanks @GonzaloPincheiraArancibia; I had no idea we can add controller into directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a code using the controller to get the type attribute.
Notice that using `bindToController` property in the directive definition, make able to access to type attribute through the scope service and the `controllerAs` alias, in this case called `ctrl`.

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .directive('jobs', jobsDirective);

    function jobsDirective() {

        return {
            restrict:'E',
            replace:true,
            controller: jobsCtrl,
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            bindToController: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/jobs.html',
            scope: {    
                type:'@'
            }
        }
    }

    jobsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'jobService'];

    function jobsCtrl($scope, jobService, $sce) {
        var vm = this,
        type = $scope.ctrl.type; 
        //USE THE TYPE ATTRIBUTE TO GET THE JOBS ACCORDING THE TYPE 
        jobService.getAllJobs(type).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            vm.jobs = data;
        });

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching me to use controller in my directive and bindToController & controllerAs. my best Christmas present so far haha

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code; I just added a controller for the directive.

```
"use strict";
/*
e.g. <jobs type="1" />
*/
angular.module('myApp').directive('jobs', jobsDirective);
angular.module('myApp').controller("jobsCtrl" ,jobsCtrl);

    jobsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'jobService'];

    function jobsCtrl($scope, jobService, $sce) {

        jobService.getAllJobs().success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.jobs = data;
        });

    }

    function jobsDirective() {

        return {
            restrict:'E',
            replace:true,
            controller: 'jobsCtrl',
            templateUrl:'templates/jobs.html',
            scope: {    
                type:'@'
            }
        }
    }
```